# Convert datetime.timedelta to minutes

Tags: python, datetime

I used Python pandas to create an output list:

```
[Timedelta('0 days 11:10:39.836405529'),
 Timedelta('0 days 00:32:24.919831223')]
```

However, my javascript chart cannot phrase it as valid input data. I want to convert this list to minutes, so my output will be something like this：

```
[274.65, 32.4]
```

Is that possible to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take the `total_seconds` and divide by 60.

```
>>> import datetime
>>> td = datetime.timedelta(seconds=90)
>>> td.total_seconds() / 60
1.5
```